# React Native: render layout with form in center, and flex background

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to make like this layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCg1K.png

That's what I have:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.sky}></View>
    <View style={styles.horizon}></View>
    <View style={styles.ground}></View>
</View>

  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  sky: {
    flex:15
  },

  ground: {
    flex:7
  },

  horizon: {
    flex:1
  },
```

But I havn't idea ho to add form in center screen

Comment: You may want to use absolute children in relation to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute to achieve.

**Update**

Something like:

```js
import {Dimensions} from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.sky}></View>
        <View style={styles.horizon}></View>
        <View style={styles.ground}></View>
        <View style={styles.center}></View>
      </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}



container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  sky: {
    flex: 15,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },

  ground: {
    flex: 7,
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },

  horizon: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "green"
  },
  center: {
    position: "absolute",
    width:200,
    height:200,
    left:(Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - 100,
    top:(Dimensions.get('window').height / 2) - 100,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "gray"
  }
```

[Code test online](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-volhard-625iu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: If you want like flex, change 80 to "30%" instead as you like.

Comment: But what if I want to set fix width to my center block ?

Comment: I've update my answer, but it get the windows width and height to calculate, it is what I could think close to your needs.

Comment: Set the width and height, and minus half of it to move away from top and left

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers, and by [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer to any
question you ask.  : )